# Microsoft Word: ContextMenu idMso for when anything is selected

Tags: ms-office, vsto

In Microsoft Word ribbon.xml, is there a ContextMenu idMso that can be used for whenever there is a selection?

Essentially, I would like to display my button whenever "Cut" and "Copy" are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up referencing multiple context menus, adding my button to each one and using the `getVisible` hook to show/hide the button.